# Strtotime with European date format

Tags: php, string, time

I'm trying to use strtotime to convert the following date:

07/09/2009 17:01:27

It's the Europe/London timezone format for 7th of September

The function is inverting the month and the days, is there any workaround?
thanks

Comment: Just swap the day and month values.

Comment: I'm not using one variable per value otherwise I'd have done that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
strtotime(07/09/2009 17:01:27 GMT);
```

or try this first maybe:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```

i guess the best answer is to not use strtotime as you can never be 100% with its accuracy

Comment: "...not use strtotime as you can never be 100% with its accuracy"
The same can be said of any function that's not understood and used properly. strtotime() is a very useful and powerful function. One solution is to always format dates (for computation purposes) as "Y-m-d".

Answer (score 21):

Change `/` for `-`, seems like PHP gets `/` as American format, and `-` as European. You can see here:

```
$date = "06/10/2011 14:28"; // 6 october 2011 2:28 pm
$otherDate = "06-10-2011 14:28"; // 6 october 2011 2:28 pm

echo $stamp = strtotime($date) . "<br />"; // outputs 1307708880
echo $otherStamp = strtotime($otherDate) . "<br />"; // outputs 1317904080

echo date("d-m", $stamp); // outputs 10-06
echo date("d-m", $otherStamp); // outputs 06-10
```

http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php#106043

Comment: The other answers mix up the month and day, this one is indeed correct.

Comment: isn't the first datestring 10th of June, hence the different UNIX timestamp on output? comments seem to suggest it would be the same date .. And edit queue for this question is full, so I'm assuming I'm not the only one mildly confused about this

Answer (score 6):

Providing you're not on Windows you can use [`strptime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php) instead, and explicitly set the format.  As OIS points out, `strptime` isn't available on Windows.

To convert from the split up year/month/day etc values to a unix timestamp you can pass them into [`mktime`](http://php.net/mktime).  Slightly fiddly, but it works.

One reason you might want to do this would be to print it in a different format using [`date`](http://php.net/date).

From the strptime php.net page:

> Example #1 strptime() example
>
> ```
> <?php
>   $format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S';
>   $strf = strftime($format);
>
>   echo "$strf\n";
>
>   print_r(strptime($strf, $format));
> ?>
> ```
>
> The above example will output
>   something similar to:
>
> 03/10/2004 15:54:19
>
> ```
> Array
> (
>     [tm_sec] => 19
>     [tm_min] => 54
>     [tm_hour] => 15
>     [tm_mday] => 3
>     [tm_mon] => 9
>     [tm_year] => 104
>     [tm_wday] => 0
>     [tm_yday] => 276
>     [unparsed] =>
> )
> ```

Comment: Note: This function is not implemented on Windows platforms.

Answer (score 4):

[DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) can handle this easily:

```
$datetime = new DateTime('07/09/2009 17:01:27', new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
echo $datetime->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/vmY54R)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick fix which should work. An alternative would be regex with named matches.

```
function eurototime($string)
{
    static $sorted = array(
        'tm_hour' => null,
        'tm_min' => null,
        'tm_sec' => null,
        'tm_mon' => null,
        'tm_mday' => null,
        'tm_year'  => null,
    );
    static $unsorted = array(
        'tm_mday',
        'tm_mon',
        'tm_year',
        'tm_hour',
        'tm_min',
        'tm_sec',

    );
    static $format = '%d/%d/%d %d:%d:%d';
    $parsed = sscanf($string, $format);
    $data = array_combine($unsorted, $parsed);
    $sortedData = array_merge($sorted, $data);
    $int = call_user_func_array('mktime', $sortedData);
    return $int;
}

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
echo eurototime(date('d/m/Y H:i:s')), "\n", time(),"\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

The top answer at the time I'm writing this which suggests using dashes works, but for anybody looking for something cleaner that both doesn't require setting up your user facing dates in a particular way or doing manual string editing I'd suggest using [DateTime::createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
$dateObject = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', '07/09/2009 17:01:27');
echo $dateObject->format('Y-m-d');
```

I definitely recommend reading the docs for that function though, it has a lot of edge cases that might cause issues for your use case.